# Python Pandas - Group into list of named tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import collections

stg = """
target predictor  value
10     predictor1     A
10     predictor1     C
10     predictor2     1
10     predictor2     2
10     predictor3     X
20     predictor1     A
20     predictor2     3
20     predictor3     Y
30     predictor1     B
30     predictor2     1
30     predictor3     X
40     predictor1     B
40     predictor2     2
40     predictor2     3
40     predictor3     X
40     predictor3     Y
50     predictor1     C
50     predictor2     3
50     predictor3     Y
60     predictor1     C
60     predictor2     4
60     predictor3     Z
"""
```

I've done this to get the list of predictors and values that have the same list of targets:

```
src = pd.read_csv(StringIO(stg), delim_whitespace=True, dtype=str)

grouped = src.groupby(["predictor","value"])['target'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

print(grouped)

    predictor value    target
0  predictor1     A     10,20
1  predictor1     B     30,40
2  predictor1     C  10,50,60
3  predictor2     1     10,30
4  predictor2     2     10,40
5  predictor2     3  20,40,50
6  predictor2     4        60
7  predictor3     X  10,30,40
8  predictor3     Y  20,40,50
9  predictor3     Z        60
```

From here I ultimately want to create a list of named tuples for each list of targets that represents the predictor and the value

```
Predicate = collections.namedtuple('Predicate',('predictor', 'value'))
```

EDIT:

To clarify, I want to create a list of Predicates so in a separate process, I can iterate them and construct query strings like so:

```
#target 10,20
data_frame.query('predictor1="A"')

#target 10,30
data_frame.query('predictor2="1"')

#target 10,30,40
data_frame.query('predictor3="X"')

#target 20,40,50
data_frame.query('predictor2="3" or predictor3="Y"')
```

I'd thought to try and use the target list and create a list of predictors and values like so

```
grouped_list = grouped.groupby('target').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

print(grouped_list)

                         predictor   value
target                                    
10,20                 [predictor1]     [A]
10,30                 [predictor2]     [1]
10,30,40              [predictor3]     [X]
10,40                 [predictor2]     [2]
10,50,60              [predictor1]     [C]
20,40,50  [predictor2, predictor3]  [3, Y]
30,40                 [predictor1]     [B]
60        [predictor2, predictor3]  [4, Z]
```

This gives me 2 columns each containing a list.  I can iterate these rows like so

```
for index, row in grouped_list.iterrows():

    print("--------")
    for pred in row["predictor"]:

        print(pred)
```

But I can't see how to get from here to something like this (which does not work but hopefully illustrates what I mean):

```
for index, row in grouped_list.iterrows():

    Predicates=[]
    for pred, val in row["predicate","value"] :

        Predicates.append(Predicate(pred, val))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2563, in get_value
return libts.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1018, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1026, in pandas._libs.tslib.get_value_box
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - I'm pretty new to python so figuring things out in a step by step fashion - there may be a far better way of achieving the above.

Cheers

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `list comprehension`:

```
L = [Predicate(x.predictor, x.value) for x in grouped.itertuples()]
print (L)

[Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='A'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='B'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='C'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='1'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='2'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='3'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='4'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='X'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='Y'), 
 Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='Z')]
```

EDIT:

```
d = {k:[Predicate(x.predictor, x.value) for x in v.itertuples()] 
                                                for k,v in grouped.groupby('target')}
print (d)

{'10,30': [Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='1')], 
 '30,40': [Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='B')], 
 '20,40,50': [Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='3'),
              Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='Y')], 
 '10,30,40': [Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='X')], 
 '10,40': [Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='2')], 
 '10,20': [Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='A')],
 '60': [Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='4'), 
        Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='Z')], 
 '10,50,60': [Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='C')]}
```

Comment: Hello, this is close to what I'm trying to get to but I need one Predicate for each combination of predictor and value e.g. Predicate(predictor='predictor2',value='3'), Predicate(predictor='predictor3',value='Y').  Ultimately i'm going to construct these items into a query string in the form 'predictor2=3 or predictor3="Y".  Does that make sense?  I'll update the question with more detail on this

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: hi @jezrael this great thank you - the only issue is I'm not able to determine which target the list of predicates came from.  Ideally I need to get something like : target="10,20", L=[Predicate(predictor='predictor1', value='A')], target="20,40,50", L=[Predicate(predictor='predictor2', value='3'), Predicate(predictor='predictor3', value='Y')]  So one separate list of predicates per target.  Is that possible?